# Adding back and empty method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Google Autocomplete and also a date plugin as a search form and I have targeted the on event with an ID element because I wish to hide it and use another.

I am using the `$state` to show or hide the block.

However because the id should only be used once I can't use it because it's causing problems (getElementById or getElementsByClass).

So instead of using `ng-show` I have managed to `empty()` or `remove()` the whole div on the page. Can I use an add() method or something similar to get it back on the other pages that I need as it clears it and I can't get it back to show?

```
if (toState.name == 'index') {
   $scope.globalData.showSearchBar = false; //cant use this
   var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#me'));
   myEl.empty();  //clears contents
}else{
    //need to add it back
}
```

Comment: sorry it's not clear for me what are you trying to achieve and why u can't use ng-show. Can you please a little bit improve your question? Also where is your code executing? Is that inside a stateChangeListener or something?

Comment: I am using 3rd party scripts that are using I'ds to target functions...I have tried to change these to classes but they are not working...my ng-show are hidden correctly but they are still in the Dom, so I need to remove them from the Dom using the empty() or remove() method but can't get them back in my if statement